# Let E a projection,calculate $f (E)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space over the field $F$ and E be a projection of $V$ and  f is an element of $F[t]$, of grade greater than or equal to 1, calculate f (E) and determine the relation between coefficients of $f$ and $f (E)$

I did the following

If $E$ is projection $E ^ n = E$ to $n \geq 1$

then $f (E) = (a_1 + a_2 +................ + a_n) (E) + a_0I$

Is it true?

What is the relation between cieficientes of $f$ and $f (E)$?

Thanks for everything and for your help

Have a good day :D

Comment: A projection $E$ satisfies $E^2 = E$, specifically, so if $f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k t^k$, then
$$f(E) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k E^k = \left(\sum_{\substack{0 \leq k \leq n\\ \text{$k$ even}}} a_k \right)I + \left(\sum_{\substack{0 \leq k \leq n\\ \text{$k$ odd}}} a_k \right)E.$$

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić   Thank you very much :D